How to show $\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow 1^-}\frac{\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x^{2}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}=1$?
$$\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow 1^-}\frac{\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x^{2}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}=1$$
Can the ratio of these integrals in the limit be interpreted as the center of mass of a rod one unit long that has density function $\rho=\frac{x}{1-x}$?
If so, then it would seem highly intuitive that the limit evaluates to $1$.
As a secondary source of reassurance that the ratio converges, I put it in Desmos.
I know that what I'm working with is $$\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow 1^-}\frac{-a-\frac{a^2}{2}+\ln(\frac{1}{1-a})}{-a+\ln(\frac{1}{1-a})}$$
Perhaps someone can show me how to evaluate this limit step-by-step?
I don't really understand in a rigorous way the concept of bounded terms being insignificant and allowed to be replaced by zero. I know that we can wave our hands and declare this to be true, but I haven't understood it in a rigorous way yet.

You can certainly evaluate these integrals directly. $\frac x{1-x}=-1+\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{x^2}{1-x}=-(1+x)+\frac1{1-x}.$

Yes, that algebraic manipulation is obvious for even a middle schooler, but I don't know how to take the limit of the natural log of $(1-x)$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from below

It goes to infinity, and the other terms are  bounded, so the ration goes to $1.$

I'll leave this question up rather than deleting it, incase anyone comes around who wants to demonstrate what you've explained rigorously and earn a quick upvote

I'm also very curious as to whether the center of mass interpretation is valid

Integrating by parts
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^a\frac{x^b}{1-x}dx=-a^b\ln(1-a)+b\int_0^a\ln(1-x)x^{b-1}dx$$
The last integral converges at $a=1,,b>0$, therefore
$$I(a,b)=-\ln(1-a)+O(1),,\text{at},,a\to1^-, ,b>0$$

Note that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2}{1-x}
&= \frac{x^2-1+1}{1-x}\\
&= \frac{x^2-1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1-x} \\
&= -\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1} + \frac{1}{1-x} \\
&= -1-x + \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align*}
$$
and similarly
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{1-x}
&= -\frac{x+1-1}{x-1} \\
&= -1 +\frac{1}{1-x} 
\end{align*}
$$
Then
$$\begin{align*}
L &:= \lim_{a \to 1^-} \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^a \frac{x^2}{1-x} \, \mathrm{d}x }{\displaystyle \int_0^a \frac{x}{1-x} \, \mathrm{d}x } \\
&= \lim_{a \to 1^-} \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^a \left[  -1-x + \frac{1}{1-x} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x }{\displaystyle \int_0^a \left[ -1 + \frac{1}{1-x}  \right]\, \mathrm{d}x } \tag{$\ast$} \\
&= \lim_{a \to 1^-} \frac{\displaystyle -x - \frac 1 2 x^2 - \ln(1-x) \bigg|_0^a}{\displaystyle -x - \ln(1-x) \bigg|_0^a}\\
&= \lim_{a \to 1^-} \frac{\displaystyle -a - \frac 1 2 a^2 - \ln(1-a)}{\displaystyle -a - \ln(1-a)}
\end{align*}$$
Since
$$
\lim_{a \to 1^-} \ln(1-a) = -\infty
$$
clearly L'Hopital's rule applies, allowing
$$\begin{align*}
L 
&\stackrel{\text{LH}}{=}\lim_{a \to 1^-}  \frac{\displaystyle -1-a+\frac{1}{1-a}}{\displaystyle -1 + \frac{1}{1-a}} \tag{$\ast\ast$}\\
&\stackrel{\text{LH}}{=} \lim_{a \to 1^-} \frac{\displaystyle -1+\frac{1}{(1-a)^2}}{\displaystyle  \frac{1}{(1-a)^2}}\\
&\stackrel{\text{LH}}{=}\lim_{a \to 1^-}  \frac{\displaystyle \frac{ 2}{(1-a)^3}}{\displaystyle  \frac{2}{(1-a)^3}}\\
&=1
\end{align*}$$
(Anecdote: Compare $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$; clearly, if we apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and differentiate $(\ast)$ w.r.t. $a$, we could get $(\ast\ast)$. This would skip a fair bit of redundancy, but require we show the integrals result in an indeterminant form via other means.)


I don't really understand in a rigorous way the concept of bounded terms being insignificant and allowed to be replaced by zero. I know that we can wave our hands and declare this to be true, but I haven't understood it in a rigorous way yet.

The rough premise is that a finite quantity has no meaningful contribution to a limit when adjacent quantities go to infinity. This is easiest to justify when polynomials are involved, since they tend to behave very nicely under L'Hopital's rule.
A very rough encapsulation of the idea can be provided by asymptotic equivalence: provided
$$
\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
$$
then you can sometimes replace $f$ with $g$ or vice versa in corresponding limits. (Here, $c \in [-\infty,+\infty]$, including the infinities.) For instance,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1
$$
so sometimes it's nice to be able to replace $\sin x$ with $x$. For instance,
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x + x^2}{x}
= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+x^2}{x}
= \infty
$$
It can lead to problems though, in certain contexts, so one should use more rigorous reasoning in general. An example perhaps being
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x \sin x
\stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{x \to \infty} x^2
= \infty
$$
but the original limit diverges. And at other times, an equivalence of this sort just proves unfruitful, and you will need better ones, e.g. as granted by Taylor's theorem.
Big-O notation sometimes helps unmask these difficulties, e.g. by writing
$$
\sin x = x + \mathcal{O}(x^3)
$$
but it's only so useful.


Can the ratio of these integrals in the limit be interpreted as the center of mass of a rod one unit long that has density function $\rho=\frac{x}{1-x}$?

Sure (in the limit of course)! Generally, given a density function $\delta$ for the appropriate dimension of space (let's just say $1$-dimensional for simplicity) for an object living in (say) $[a,b]$, then the object has first moment
$$
\int_a^b x \cdot \delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
and mass
$$
\int_a^b \delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
so its center of mass is at the ratio of those two:
$$
\text{center of mass (1D over $[a,b]$)}
= \frac{\displaystyle \int_a^b x \cdot \delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x}{\displaystyle \int_a^b  \delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x}
$$

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous  on $[0,1)$ and
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^-}g(x)=+\infty.$
If the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1^-}{f(x)\over g(x)}$ exists then by the l'Hospital rule we get
$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-}{\int\limits_0^x f(t)\,dt \over \int\limits_0^x g(t)\,dt}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}{f(x)\over g(x)}$$
In the OP case $f(x)=x^2/(1-x),$ $g(x)=1/(1-x).$ Thus $f(x)/g(x)=x$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1^-}{f(x)\over g(x)}=1.$
The assumptions are satisfied as $f(x)\ge {1\over 4}g(x)$ for $x\ge {1\over 4}$ and
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\int\limits_0^xg(t)\,dt =\lim_{x\to 1^-}[-\log(1-x)]=+\infty $$
